# In vim, how can I quickly switch between tabs?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, tabs, gnome-terminal

In gnome-terminal, I can just press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, etc.) to switch to specific tabs. I can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + (<kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDn</kbd>) to cycle through tabs (admittedly less convenient, but it can be remapped).

If I want to use vim tabs instead of gnome-terminal tabs, typing `:tabn` and `:tabp` is quite cumbersome. I could map them to keyboard shortcuts, but that is still a lot less convenient than jumping directly to tab 4 with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>.

Is there a faster way to switch between tabs in vim?

Comment: I'm using Cygwin's Gvim, and Ctrll+PgUp/PgDown works.  Unfortunately, Ctrl+PgUp seems to be ignored a lot of the time unless I Alt+Tab to another application and Alt+Tab back.

Answer (score 424):

Next tab: <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

Prior tab: <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

Numbered tab: <kbd>*nnn*</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

Comment: I know that I could type `nnn` `g` `t`, but I want to do it *quickly*, i.e. `Alt + nnn` or `Ctrl + nnn`. But `Alt + n` is already taken by gnome-terminal, and binding to `Ctrl + n` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: What about mapping function keys to `nnn` `g` `t`? E.g., `:map <F2> 2gt`. There is the problem that `<F1>` is often mapped by GNOME to its help facility. Or you could choose some key you don't use often in normal mode, say the comma, and map it like this: `:map , gt`. Then `1,` will take you to tab 1, `2,` to tab 2, and so on.

Comment: I found it very convenient to use '<' and '>'

Comment: Last tab: `:tabl` command (full form: `:tablast`).

Answer (score 82):

Why not make use of your leader (my leader is mapped to <kbd>Space</kbd>):

```
" Go to tab by number
noremap <leader>1 1gt
noremap <leader>2 2gt
noremap <leader>3 3gt
noremap <leader>4 4gt
noremap <leader>5 5gt
noremap <leader>6 6gt
noremap <leader>7 7gt
noremap <leader>8 8gt
noremap <leader>9 9gt
noremap <leader>0 :tablast<cr>
```

You can use the settings below to toggle between the current and last active tab (here it is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, i.e., `<c-l>`):

```
" Go to last active tab

au TabLeave * let g:lasttab = tabpagenr()
nnoremap <silent> <c-l> :exe "tabn ".g:lasttab<cr>
vnoremap <silent> <c-l> :exe "tabn ".g:lasttab<cr>
```

Comment: You need `au TabLeave * let g:lasttab = tabpagenr()` for `c-l` to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119754/switch-to-last-active-tab-in-vim

Comment: I'd add `<leader>h/l` for `gT` and `gt`

Comment: I think this answer is the most appropriate regarding the OP needs expressed.

Comment: Here is a lua equivalent for the last active tab.  Sorry about the formatting:
`local lastTab = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("LastTab", { clear = true })`
`vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("TabLeave",
  { pattern = "*", command = "let g:lasttab = tabpagenr()", group = lastTab }
)
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', 'da', ':exe "tabn ".g:lasttab<CR>', {noremap = true, silent = true})
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('v', 'da', ':exe "tabn ".g:lasttab<CR>', {noremap = true, silent = true})
`

Answer (score 44):

This is the easiest way that I found, to switch between tabs faster and simple. 
Add next lines to your .vimrc and enjoy it, more tricks about vim tabs [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages).

```
nnoremap <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>
```

Now you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> to go left and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> to go right.

Or just use:
<kbd>1gt</kbd> to go to tab one,
<kbd>2gt</kbd> to go to tab two,
<kbd>3gt</kbd> to go to tab three, etc... now you have the idea.

Comment: I think this is the best answer here. Very convenient to have. I just disabled those system keybindings in OS X for making them system independent.

Comment: Use arrow keys will slow you down. I have them disabled

Comment: Yup... Best answer!

Comment: Sadly "Ctrl" gave me problems in vmplayer, so I changed to keys "Backspace" and "Enter".

Comment: Mac users: you may need to disable the default Mission Control spaces keyboard shortcuts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719135/how-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-mac-os-x#answer-15719195

Comment: @AskandLearn I think <C-Right> is a lot quicker than :tn repeated many times

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: On Mac it worked for me with `command` +  `Ctrl` + `arrow-keys`

Comment: I thought one of the key characteristics of vim was that all commands used plain characters. No CTRL or ALT or Fn. Really, something faster than ngt? (Don't tell me you have more than 9 tabs open). 3 keystrokes? I upvoted this answer because of the last part of the asnwer.

Answer (score 36):

As I am on a Mac and not using MacVim (but plain vim within a terminal) I have had some difficulty with key combinations not being sent through to the terminal.

The most-compatible (and for me most comfortable) way to switch tabs quickly comes from the [Vim Wikia site](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Alternative_tab_navigation).

Place in your `.vimrc` file:

```
nnoremap H gT
nnoremap L gt
```

Now `Shift-h` (capital H) and `Shift-l` (capital L) will switch you quickly between tabs, and follows the convention that `h` and `l` correspond to left and right in vim on a regular qwerty keyboard.

Comment: I love this solution, intuitive and vim-like. No arrow keys needed.

Comment: I agree. A very nice solution

Comment: this is really an intuitive solution. Thank you!

Comment: Normal mode `H`/`L` is bound to vim's "move cursor to top/bottom" of the page fyi.

Answer (score 5):

(Unfortunately) vim also uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd>/<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to cycle through tabs. You'll need to use `map` to map `tabn`/`tabp` to something usable.

Comment: This matches Excel's hotkeys for switching tabs. Those are already in my muscle memory so perfect for me!

Comment: I noticed this behavior but couldn't find any place inside the help explaining this. Do you know if there's any?

Answer (score 4):

Add these to .vimrc to enable tab navigation hot keys:

> `<ctrl-l>` toggle between 2 most recent tabs;
>
> `<ctrl-j/k>` goto the last/next tab;
>
> `<ctrl-t>` open a new tab.

```
" tab navigation: Alt or Ctrl+Shift may not work in terminal:
" http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Alternative_tab_navigation
" Tab navigation like Firefox: only 'open new tab' works in terminal
nnoremap <C-t>     :tabnew<CR>
inoremap <C-t>     <Esc>:tabnew<CR>
" move to the previous/next tabpage.
nnoremap <C-j> gT
nnoremap <C-k> gt
" Go to last active tab 
au TabLeave * let g:lasttab = tabpagenr()
nnoremap <silent> <c-l> :exe "tabn ".g:lasttab<cr>
vnoremap <silent> <c-l> :exe "tabn ".g:lasttab<cr>
```

Comment: Is it possible to map <Ctrl>-<Tab> to the last toggle tab function. I've tried `nnoremap <silent> <C-Tab> :exe "tabn ".g:lasttab<cr>` and `vnoremap <silent> <C-Tab> :exe "tabn ".g:lasttab<cr>` without luck.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using gvim or similar (i.e., something outside of the terminal), you can imitate the `gnome-terminal` behaviour you describe with:

```
" Map alt-x keys to jump to a tab
for i in range(1, 8)
  execute "nmap \<M-" . i . "> " . i . "gt"
endfor
nmap <M-9> :tablast<CR>
```

So `alt-1` jumps to the first tab, etc. But `alt-9` jumps to the last tab (as in Chrome).

You might want to wrap this in `if has("gui_running")` (although this doesn't seem to work with Neovim), or put this in `.gvimrc`.

Comment: Lol I don't know why Although This is the Only answer that satisfies the question Yet the least up-voted one

Comment: @MahmoudSalah - it's likely b/c this Q&A comes up 1st on google and most ppl looking for this solution aren't on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I like to switch windows/tabs with [fzf-vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim). It is fast and

For instance you can make a bindkey `<leader>w` which calls `Windows` or `Buffers`. Also Jumps  and Changes  are useful tools for fast switching.

**Buffers**:

[image]

**Windows** :

[image]

Here some maps for fzf I am using frequently:

```
nnoremap <silent><Leader>f :Files<CR>
nnoremap <silent><leader>j :Jumps<CR>
nnoremap <silent><leader>c :Changes<CR>
nnoremap <silent><Leader>m :Marks<CR>
nnoremap <silent><Leader>w :Windows<CR>
nnoremap <silent><Leader>h :Helptags<CR>
nnoremap <silent><Leader>b :Buffers<CR>
nnoremap <silent><Leader>bl :BLines<CR>
```

Comment: `:Windows` (or `:W`) worked for me.  Thanks!
Fun fact: I have been accidentally pressing `:W` for _years_ and immediately backing out without ever looking at what it actually did! 

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem the same as you,
but later I find out what I really need might be a ***Marker***.
Especially when using uppercase characters like `mA` ,
It will take you to your marked tab by using "`A" as fast as it can.
Hope it can help.