# How can I switch vim mode quickly?

Tags: linux, vim, text-editors, text-editing, vi

This question is not the same as [In vim, how can I quickly switch between tabs?](https://superuser.com/questions/410982/in-vim-how-can-i-quickly-switch-between-tabs), but what I want is a bit similar to it, since we are all trying to find shortcuts when editing with vim:)

Now I am in the following mode:

```
set number
syntax on
colorscheme desert
```

**Can I switch to the other mode quickly without typing 3 command**?

That would be more convenient than inputing lots of commands.

```
set nonumber
syntax off
colorscheme blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Toggling the `number` setting is explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762515/vim-remap-key-to-toggle-line-numbering):

```
set number
nnoremap <F2> :set nonumber!<CR>
```

Toggling the `syntax` highlighting is explained in [the vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html):

```
:map <F7> :if exists("g:syntax_on") <Bar>
    \   syntax off <Bar>
    \ else <Bar>
    \   syntax enable <Bar>
    \ endif <CR>
```

And there is a script to cycle through `colorscheme` options at [wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switch_color_schemes).