# integrate tmux tabs with vim tabs

Tags: vim, tmux, tabs, iterm2, iterm

I'm trying to simplify the way that I navigate between tabs in my terminal. Using `ssh <workstation> -t 'tmux -CC attach'`, I can get iTerm to display `tmux` tabs as native macOS tabs (and therefore use the normal macOS keyboard shortcuts `command-{` and `command-}` for tab navigation), and I'd like to go one step further and get `vim` tabs within `tmux` to be treated the same way.

Is there a way to make `vim` create `tmux` tabs, instead of its own native tab type?

Alternatively, is there a way to make `tmux` somehow know that when I hit `command-{` or `command-}` in iTerm, that it should send a special key code to `vim` to make it switch tabs? (And ideally, is there any way to tell if I'm at the first or last tab in `vim`, so that I jump to the next `tmux` tab instead of wrapping to the next `vim` tab?)

(I've seen a way to integrate splits [here](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator), but if I understand right, that doesn't do anything related to tabs.)

Comment: Someone is overusing tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The normal mode command `gt`, can also be obtained using the ex mode command `:tn`.

Similarly the normal mode command `gT` can also be obtained using the ex mode command
`:tp`.

Ref: https://superuser.com/a/884981/658319

Next, you can map the Mac command key in iTerm2 using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46018502/4752883

Let me know if you have any questions.